# How to ignore characters while tokenizing Keras

Tags: python, keras, nlp, tokenize

I am trying to train & build a tokenizer using Keras & here is the snippet of code where I am doing this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

txt1="""What makes this problem difficult is that the sequences can vary in length,
be comprised of a very large vocabulary of input symbols and may require the model 
to learn the long term context or dependencies between symbols in the input sequence."""

#txt1 is used for fitting 
tk = Tokenizer(nb_words=2000, lower=True, split=" ",char_level=False)
tk.fit_on_texts(txt1)

#convert text to sequencech
t= tk.texts_to_sequences(txt1)

#padding to feed the sequence to keras model
t=pad_sequences(t, maxlen=10)
```

Upon testing which words the Tokenizer has learned, it gives that it has only learned characters but not words.

```
print(tk.word_index)
```

output:

```
{'e': 1, 't': 2, 'n': 3, 'a': 4, 's': 5, 'o': 6, 'i': 7, 'r': 8, 'l': 9, 'h': 10, 'm': 11, 'c': 12, 'u': 13, 'b': 14, 'd': 15, 'y': 16, 'p': 17, 'f': 18, 'q': 19, 'v': 20, 'g': 21, 'w': 22, 'k': 23, 'x': 24}
```

why it does not have any words ?

Furthermore, if I print t, it clearly shows that, words are ignored and each word is tokenized char by char

```
print(t)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  0  0 ...  0  0 22]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0 10]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  4]
 ...
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0 12]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  1]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  0  0  0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the error. 
If the text was passed as the following:

```
txt1=["""What makes this problem difficult is that the sequences can vary in length,
be comprised of a very large vocabulary of input symbols and may require the model 
to learn the long term context or dependencies between symbols in the input sequence."""]
```

with the brackets, it will work just fine. 
Here is the new output of t:

```
print(t)


[[30 31 32 33 34  5  2  1  4 35]]
```

which means that the function takes a list rather than just a text

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
txt1='What makes this problem difficult is that the sequences can vary in length,
be comprised of a very large vocabulary of input symbols and may require the model 
to learn the long term context or dependencies between symbols in the input sequence.'

t = Tokenizer()
t.fit_on_texts(txt1)
# summarize what was learned
print(t.word_counts)
print(t.document_count)
print(t.word_index)
print(t.word_docs)
```

copy paste it and run .
I am assuming the problem first is in the quotations around the input text "you got 3 quotations". Secondly you dont have to perform `t= tk.texts_to_sequences(txt1)` 
instead do this

```
encoded_txt = t.texts_to_matrix(txt1, mode='count')
print(encoded_txt)
```

Other workaround is

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
text = txt1
# estimate the size of the vocabulary
words = set(text_to_word_sequence(text))
vocab_size = len(words)
print(vocab_size)
```

Comment: That is not what is required, + it did not give me what I needed :(